# Adding a horizontal scrollbar properly on a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a calendar table that can scroll horizontally while keeping the left column frozen.  I've managed to get it working in using two different methods but have small display issues with both of them.

Can someone please assist with getting either one (or both) to work properly?
A pure css/html solution would be preferable, but I don't mind adding javascript should it be needed.

## Method 1:

The first method involves creating a container table containing a single row with two cells and with a table in each of those cells.  Left column contains the row headers and right column contains a scrollable div with a wide table inside that gets scrolled left and right.

See:    https://jsfiddle.net/rjcxc62a/

The problem with this solution is that I'm using the bootstrap grid and if I specify the width for the div in the column on the right as 100% (so that the entire table can display as 100%), then the table fully displays on the page with no scrollbar which means the whole page needs to scroll left/right (see .leave-plan .data-holder class below).  That effectively means that the grid isn't responsive and doesn't resize with the window size.

```
.leave-plan { width: 100%; font-size: 9pt; }
.leave-plan table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; display: block; table-layout: fixed; }
.leave-plan .data-holder { width: 400px; overflow-x: auto; display: block; }
```

## Method 2:

The second solution involves creating a single table and specifying the left column as top-most absolute.  This option works with bootstrap and resizes accordingly but I can't seem to specify a fixed width for the columns.  I want every column to be exactly 25px wide but I simply cannot seem to get it right.  The column widths are being generated based on the cell contents which ranges from 13px to 18px even though Google shows that the 25px from the css is being used to format the cell. (This again works correctly with the first solution)

Here are the important css parts:

```
.Calendar-Wrapper { overflow: auto; width: 100% }
.Calendar-Wrapper table { table-layout: fixed; }
.Calendar-Wrapper table tbody th:first-child { position: absolute; z-index: 1; width: 200px; background-color: white; text-align: left; }
.Calendar-Wrapper table td { height: 20px; width: 25px; }
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/e4zzst8c/

Answer (score 0):

Followed **your method 1** I changed the position of header column to absolute and z-index to 9 (make sure it's always on top), position of data column to relative. Check demo below:

HTML:

```
<td class="fluid-col">
                    <div class="data-holder">
                        <table class="data">
```

CSS:

```
.leave-plan {width: 100%; font-size: 9pt; display: block; position: relative;}
.leave-plan .data-holder { display: block; }
.leave-plan { width: 100%; font-size: 9pt;overflow-x: auto; display: block; position: relative; }
.leave-plan .names {position: absolute;top: 2px;background: #fff; z-index: 9;}
.fluid-col {
      position: relative;
      width:100%;
      left: 200px;
      overflow:auto;
    }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rjcxc62a/6/

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to solve my issues.  Just had to turn the overflow off on the data-holder to prevent 2 scrollbars from showing.

Comment: There seems to be a slight issue when the table size becomes too small.  If I fixed the cell width to 25px and the table width becomes smaller than 650px, then 3 scrollbars appear and I have to scroll all 3 of them to scroll to the far-right side.  Any idea how to fix / improve it?

Comment: Ok, got some more information.  It seems that the scrollbars popping up happens when the total width becomes smaller than the data-holder width - 250px (basically the 250px we reserved for the left column).

Comment: Hmm. Ok let me check it.

Comment: after i removed the overflow property of .leave-plan. the 2nd horizonal scroll bar is gone. Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/rjcxc62a/7/